# Disable on('click') for elements inside of a specific div

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```js
  div1 = $('#div1');
    div1.on('click', function(){
     alert('Hi!');
    });
```

```html
 <div id="div1">
     <p>Some random text</p>
     <div id="div2">
       <form>
         <input type="text">
         <input type="submit">
       </form>
     </div>
    </div>
```

With this code I successfully get an alert saying "Hi" when I click the `#div1` element, but how can I exclude the `#div2` element and all the content inside of it (e.g. the form and the inputs) from the `on('click')` event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to be more specific and use the child selector as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        div1 = $('#div1>p');
        div1.on('click', function(){
         alert('Hi!');
        });
    });
</script>
```

this will exclude your form elements or anything else in the second div element.